# Forms authentication sharing - 3.5 WebForms app and 4.5 MVC app

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, webforms

We have a .NET Framework 3.5 WebForms application and a .NET Framework 4.5 MVC application, and we want these applications to share the same login cookie so the user doesn't have to authenticate twice.

So I set it up in the web.config by using the same machine key/decryption keys, and this works fine however users are getting *occassional* issues where the MVC application doesn't think the user is logged in. This is something I can't replicate it, but it's happening to users quite a bit.

Are there any special considerations I need to take as they are different .NET Framework versions? Relevant parts of the web.config below

WebForms app:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
   <forms timeout="2880" name="EOSFormsAuth" />
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="Key1Here" decryptionKey="Key2Here" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

MVC App

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="EOSFormsAuth" />
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="Key1Here" decryptionKey="Key2Here" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Thanks!